# Track how long any app is foreground

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I want to track which games I am playing and for how long I have played them.

Is there any software that can track and keep log of how much time any of my applications are foreground?

Comment: I don't think Steam does this for non-steam games. I have couple of non-steam software, playing time is not tracked - only when did you last launched it is tracked.

Comment: I think it is great! Something I didn't know about, and catered to what I wanted. How can I choose your answer as the solution?

Comment: Hi Kalel, this question is off-topic, hence no answer from me.  It should be closed, or you could delete it yourself.

Comment: Honestly, I never cared about the rules. Rules matter the least when they oppose knowledge. So matters naught if it is labeled offtopic or not - thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Rescue Time](https://www.rescuetime.com/) application can do this logging, not only games but all of apps and websites.